# JSP declaration scriptlet access bean

Tags: java, jsp

I got a situation with a project I'm working on (not my code). I'm a somewhat beginner with JSPs, so it would be great to find out what happened.

So I have a code like this (it's a lot simplified):

```
<jsp:useBean id="accessManager" scope="session" class="AccessManager" />
<%! Object x = accessManager %>
<% Object y = accessManager %>
```

The second line doesn't work, it doesn't know what accessManager is. The third line (y) works.

I know that declaration scriptlets translate into java class attributes or methods, which are executed once when the jsp in initialized, and normal scriptlets (<% %>) are translated into the _jspService method. But what's the scope of the two? Or why can't I access the bean from the declaration scriptlet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!` is used to specify a no-context.

If you use `<%! Object x = accessManager; %>` it will produce Code like this.

```
class Index {
  Object x = accessManager;
}
```

If you use `<% Object x = accessManager; %>` it will produce Code like this:

```
class Index {
  public void foo(){
    Object x = accessManager;
  }
}
```

Look at  `C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-*\work\Catalina\localhost\*\org\apache\jsp\` for the Generated .java-File.

(The example is simplyfied.)

Comment: I updated the code. The question was more related to the difference between <%! and <% when accessing beans. So I think your first answer was best (with the static context). Btw, is it really static context?

Comment: No its no-context, its not function-scope, its not static-scope. **Its class-scope**! I simplyfied my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use either of the declaration depending on where you would like to add the code in the servlet.

Scriptlet of the form `<% code %>` that are inserted into the servlet's service method. So, it becomes part of your application logic.

Scriptlet Declarations of the form `<%! code %>` that are inserted into the body of the servlet class, outside of any existing methods. So, it becomes part of the servlet class. One very good use of it is to insert a method into servlet and use that method from within service method (under tag `<% code %>`) For ex:

```
<%!

public int sum(int a, int b) {

return a + b;
}

%>
```